# CLLocationCoordinate2D to CLLocation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I have the following loop in my viewDidLoad:

```
for(int i=1; i<[eventsArray count]; i++) {
    NSArray *componentsArray = [[eventsArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if([componentsArray count] >=6) {
        Koordinate *coord = [[Koordinate alloc] init];
        coord.latitude = [[componentsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
        coord.longtitude = [[componentsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        coord.magnitude = [[componentsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
        coord.depth = [[componentsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
        coord.title = [componentsArray objectAtIndex:4];
        coord.strasse = [componentsArray objectAtIndex:5];
        coord.herkunft = [componentsArray objectAtIndex:6];
        coord.telefon = [componentsArray objectAtIndex:7];
        coord.internet = [componentsArray objectAtIndex:8];
        [eventPoints addObject:coord];
    }
}
```

`coord` is of Type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

How can I use `coord` in the following method? I need this to get distance between two coords:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

}
```

Comment: `coord` is not a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, `coord` is an object you created yourself, an instance of `Koordinate`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`CLLocation` has an init method that takes a `latitude` and `longitude`:

```
-(id)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude
```

Then use the following method to get the distance between two CLLocation objects:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Comment: What kind of distance is this? Great circle? Rhumb line?

Comment: I believe it's Great Circle, but the method "getDistanceFrom" has been deprecated.  It was replaced with "distanceFromLocation".

Answer (score 15):

Simple

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
```

Answer (score 12):

For the Swift crowd,

I have a method called "fetchCafesArroundLocation" which is refreshed after the map gets moved around.  This is how I handled getting the Lat and Lon into CLLocation from CLLocationCoordiate2d and then passed the CLLocation variable to the handling method.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){

    var centre = mapView.centerCoordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D

    var getLat: CLLocationDegrees = centre.latitude
    var getLon: CLLocationDegrees = centre.longitude


    var getMovedMapCenter: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: getLat, longitude: getLon)

    self.lastLocation = getMovedMapCenter
    self.fetchCafesAroundLocation(getMovedMapCenter)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> “how can i use my instance as CLLocation?”

You can't, because it isn't one. You need to [create one](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithLatitude:longitude:).

Don't forget to release what you alloc. See [the memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Answer (score 0):

If coord is a `CCLocationCoordinate2D`, then you can assign the newLocation from
the

```
**- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation**
```

delegate by getting both of the `latitude` and `longitude` properties of coordinate property of the `CLLocation` as below:

```
coord.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
coord.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift extension for if you're doing `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `CLLocation` conversions a lot, with a built-in [check for validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273107/how-to-check-that-cllocationcoordinate2d-is-not-empty).

Strange that there is not a convenience initializer built in to Core Location.

```
extension CLLocation {
    convenience init?(_ coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        guard CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coordinate2D) else { return nil }
        self.init(latitude: coordinate2D.latitude, longitude: coordinate2D.longitude)
    }
}
```

use like so:

```
let location2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.3346, longitude: -122.0090)
let location = CLLocation(location2D)
```