# Calculating distance from GPS location

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, location

I am working on Xcode project and I got some problems.
In my app, I have a GPS location and I got some taxi service around in 1000 meters radius. I would like to find the closest service near by me. The taxi service location is parsed from JSON. It look like that

```
NSNumber * latitude = [[diction objectAtIndex:13]objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"lng is =>%@", latitude);
NSNumber * longitude = [[diction objectAtIndex:13]objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"lat is =>%@", longitude);
```

Moreover, I have my own location like that:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"latitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"longitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
```

How can I subtract the latitude and longitude above in order to find the closest service.
Best Regards.

Comment: [take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2318927/119114)

Answer (score 2):

```
 CLLocation *oldLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]];
    double distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
```

use this may help You, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I did not clearly understand your code, the oldLocation means the current location? and the newLocation is the location of services around right? Base on my code, we have:    CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]]; is that correct? lat and long in newLocation is the value that I got from JSON data. Thanks again and I deeply appreciate your help.